# How to temporarily suppress warnings in R

Tags: r

Currently I write:

```
warn = getOption("warn")
options(warn=-1)
foo()
options(warn=warn)
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Since `options` returns the value previously set, you can save a line: `warn<-options(warn=-1);foo();options(warn)`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use `suppressWarnings()`:

```
suppressWarnings(foo())
```

Answer (score 5):

You wrap an expression in `suppressWarnings()` (yet here `foo()` returns an error, not a warning).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip more than one warning, you can wrap your code into `withCallingHandlers()` function.

For example:

```
withCallingHandlers({
    print("prt1")
    warning("warn1")
    message("msg1")
    print("prt2")
    warning("warn2")
    message("msg2")
},
warning = function() { return(NULL) })
```

There is also a possibility to omit messages(), by adding `message = function() { return(NULL) })` as an extra argument in the `withCallingHandlers()` function.
Moreover, there is an argument to pass your error function handler, but, when an error appears, it goes into the error handler function and won't execute remaining code in brackets.